# Finding libraries that were installed into a directory with pip install -t

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a directory that I'm installing packages into with:

```
pip install -t mytargetdirectory somepackagename
```

Which works great, but when I do a pip freeze, the name of these packages don't seem to appear. Is there a way to easily get the packages that were installed into a given target directory? Ex, if I do something like:

```
pip install -t mytargetdirectory requests
```

Is there a way to get that requests was installed in mytargetdirectory or just simply list all packages in that directory?

Comment: Can’t you just use a directory listing of that target folder? `pip` doesn’t really do magic. It just puts the packages into folders there.

Comment: You cannot do it with pip but if you want a record just add the data to a file i.e package/target when you use pip or simply ls if there are only packages there

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is there a way to record that info with pip? Any clarification would be great.

Comment: @TJ1S, not that I know of but trivial to create a bash or python script to record the info for you.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks for the clarification - didn't know if you were referring to something like setup.py's --record option.